# merge two xml using groovy script or xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, groovy

I have two xmls and it needs to be merged using groovy for xslt mapping.

Structure of XML-1:

```html
<EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>77</userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>78</userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>79</userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
</EmployeeTime>
```

Structure of XML-2 -

```html
<n0:ZHTR_LEAVE_SAL_ADVANCEResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
         <E_LEAVEDATA>
            <item>
               <PERNR>00000077</PERNR>
               <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
               <DAYS/>
               <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
            </item>
            <item>
               <PERNR>00000078</PERNR>
               <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
               <DAYS/>
               <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
            </item>
            <item>
               <PERNR>00000078</PERNR>
               <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
               <DAYS/>
               <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
            </item>
         </E_LEAVEDATA>
      </n0:ZHTR_LEAVE_SAL_ADVANCEResponse>
```

I need to merge it and get an response as below -

```html
<EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>
            <PERNR>77</PERNR>
            <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
            <DAYS/>
            <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
        </userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>
            <PERNR>78</PERNR>
            <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
            <DAYS/>
            <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
        </userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
    <EmployeeTime>
        <ABC>xyz</ABC>
        <userId>
            <PERNR>79</PERNR>
            <AMOUNT>0.0</AMOUNT>
            <DAYS/>
            <DATE>2020-02-29</DATE>
        </userId>
        <ABC1>xyz1</ABC1>
    </EmployeeTime>
</EmployeeTime>
```

The merged response should enrich the the userId tag inside the XML-1

Please note that the  can be repeated n-times and same applies for

Can some help me with the code XSLT or groovy?

Regards,
Akash

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please show us the code?

Comment: yes, please see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume the XML1 is ECRESPONSE and XML-2 is S4RESPONSE -

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
       def properties = message.getProperties();
       def ecmessage = properties.get("ECRESPONSE");
       def s4message = properties.get("S4RESPONSE");
       String combinemessage = ecmessage+"<S4Response>"+s4message+"</S4Response>";
        def messageLog = messageLogFactory.getMessageLog(message);
messageLog.addAttachmentAsString("ResponsePayloadCombine:", "--"+combinemessage+"--", "text/plain");
       return message;
}
```